# Count resources having a property of a certain type in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have data in a triple store and would like to compute the following:

how many resources 'x' have the object property 'op' with at least 2 different resources 'r' of similar type 'R' as values?

here is a example of such data in turtle syntax:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com>

ex:doc1 
  a ex:Document ;
  ex:mentions p1, p2, p3 .

ex:doc2 
  a ex:Document ;
  ex:mentions p4, p5 .

ex:p1
  a ex:Person ;
  ex:hasRole ex:r1 .

ex:p2
  a ex:Person ;
  ex:hasRole ex:r1 .

ex:p3
  a ex:Person ;
  ex:hasRole ex:r2 .

ex:p4
  a ex:Person ;
  ex:hasRole ex:r1 .

ex:p5
  a ex:Person ;
  ex:hasRole ex:r2 .

ex:r1
  a ex:Role1 . 

ex:r2
  a ex:Role2 .
```

The objective is to count resources such as `ex:doc1` which has 2 `ex:mentions` having similar roles (`r1` of type `ex:Role1`). Here the result will be 1, leaving aside ex:doc2`.

The strategy would be:

1. identify resources having the desired property, i.e. documents (doc) having object properties (mentions) pointing on resources (person), these resources having themselves properties (hasRole) of similar values (the role)).
2. count them.

I have difficulties with step 1.
For example, this query returns all docs having a p1 with Role1, even if there is only one p (p1) having this property.

```
SELECT distinct ?doc
WHERE
{
    ?doc a ex:Document .
    ?doc ex:mentions ?p1 .
    ?doc ex:mentions ?p2 .
    ?p1 ex:hasRole ?r1 .
    ?p2 ex:hasRole ?r1 .
    ?r1 a ex:Role1 .
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data wasn't quite usable (there were no prefixes on the p1, p2, etc., resources), but after fixing that, I was able to use the following query.  You were pretty close;  the trick is that you need to **filter(?p1 != ?p2)** to ensure that you're getting different values of the ex:mentions property.  Then you can just check that they have a role with a common type with **?p1 ex:hasRole/a ?roleType . ?p2 ex:hasRole/a ?roleType**, or even more concisely, **?roleType ^(a/ex:hasRole) ?p1, ?p2**.  Then, in the counting, you only want to count *distinct* values of **?document**, so you need **(count(distinct ?document) as ?nDocuments)**:

```sql
prefix ex: <http://example.com>

select
  #-- count ?document, but only count *distinct* values
  #-- of ?document.
  (count(distinct ?document) as ?nDocuments)

where {
  #-- get documents that have two distinct 
  #-- values for the ex:mentions property
  ?document a ex:Document ; ex:mentions ?p1, ?p2
  filter(?p1 != ?p2)

  #-- then check that they have a common role type
  ?roleType ^(a/ex:hasRole) ?p1, ?p2
}
```

```
--------------
| nDocuments |
==============
| 2          |
--------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! and sorry for the incomplete data. I was missing the filter, and with your example I learned how to write SPARQL stuff more concisely.

Comment: I hit enter too early. As an additional question: besides of practicing, would you recommend this book : Learning SPARQL by Bob DuCharme? (http://www.learningsparql.com/) Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @chris Thank you for the suggested edit.  It was rejected, probably because those kind of technical details are usually better addressed in the comments.  While there was a bug in my code, I think there was in your edit, too.  I *think* (but I'm not sure), that OP didn't necessarily care that the distinct persons had some particular role in common, but that they each had roles with the same type.  E.g., **p1 hasRole r1a . r1a a Role1** and **p2 hasRole r1b . r1b a Role1** would still count.  As such, I've updated my answer.